# Pascal Triangle in Lisp

Tags: java, lisp, common-lisp

I just started learning Lisp and I am having trouble understanding what [this code from Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#Common_Lisp) says:

```
(defun pascal (n)
   (genrow n '(1)))

(defun genrow (n l)
   (when (< 0 n)   //is the command "when" something like if in Java?
       (print l)
       (genrow (1- n) (cons 1 (newrow l)))))

(defun newrow (l)
   (if (> 2 (length l))
      '(1)
      (cons (+ (car l) (cadr l)) (newrow (cdr l)))))
```

I've been looking at some websites about lisp but it still confusing. The only programming language I know is Java. If someone could please explain in Java what the bold parts say, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lisp uses prefix notation because things that are usually operators (ie +, -, >) in other languages are considered functions in Lisp.  `(+ 1 1)` in Lisp is equivalent to `1 + 1;` in Java.  You could think of it as calling an add function with 1 and 1 as arguments: `add(1, 1)`  It just takes some getting used to.

So `(> 2 (length l))` is equivalent to to `2 > length(l)`

The `'` in `'(1)` tells Lisp to treat what follows as a literal.  So instead of Lisp looking for a function called `1` (which is what would happen without the backtick) it returns a list containing 1 as an element.  An equivalent way of saying that in Lisp is `(quote (1))` which returns the literal list containing 1.

Comment: So, when I call the genrow method, I am passing in n and a list?

Comment: Exactly.  I just saw that you asked about `when` also.  The `when` function (actually a macro) is just like an `if` statement in Java.  The difference is that in Lisp, the normal `if` function only has one "then" statement, followed by an "else" statement.  The `when` macro allows for multiple "then" statements.  See [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html) for more.

Comment: @nonex You shoulnd't point to elisp docs when talking about Common Lisp, the CLHS is a better reference. Particulary when elisp doesn't match CL's definitions. Elisp's if takes multiple else clauses, not so in CL. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm